# Passing-by-Value Langugages?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

If a computer language said to be "passing-by-value"

Can I say the following:

1) Primitive types are pass-by-value, and a local copy will be made in a function.
2) Object are pass-reference-by-value, a reference copy will be made in a function.

I know this is correct in JavaScript and Python. It it valid saying this in PHP, Java, .Net...?

Comment: Pass-by-value means pass-by-value. It does not automatically imply any difference between primitive types and objects. There's no general statement one can make.

Comment: No you absolutely cannot say any such thing. What makes you think you can?

Comment: In tcl, everything is passed by value in the strictest sense - objects (even multi gigabyte ones) are copied verbatim and passed into the function. You can't pass references because the language has no references or pointers at all. Instead you can emulate it by passing a string which is the variable name you want to reference and then use that value to grab that variable from the caller's stack.

Comment: This is the reason I call javascript's semantics "pass by reference copy" to differentiate it from real pass by value languages.

Answer (score 1):

The best example of a pass-by-value languages off the top of my head is [Go](http://golang.org): it passes everything by value which means everything is copied on assignment, which also includes passing actual values to formal parameters of functions when those are called.  This includes values of array types: the *contents* of arrays are copied.  And while Go has no "classes" it does have structural types and their instances are also literally copied on assignment.

The only "twist" (which is only "a twist" for those coming from Python, PHP and the langues of their ilk where instances of classes are "special" and are passed by reference) is that Go supports pointers, and you can take a pointer of any addressable value (let's not dig deeper into what this does precisely mean) and then you can pass that pointer around.  While that pointer's *value* will be *copied* on assignments (because everything is passed by value), you can use it to access the value it points to indirectly — hence essentially obtaining the semantics of Python and PHP's objects, just *explicitly.*

Go also has several built-in types with "handle semantics" (or "reference semantics", if you like): that is, instances of these types are just "handles" (or references) to complex in-memory structures.  Like everything else, their values are copied when assigned/passed around but like with pointers, the actual in-memory structures these values refer to are not copied and hence shared.  These types are very few, are explicitly documented to behave the way they do and require specialized instantiation (using the [`make()` built-in function](http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)).

Another good example of a pass-by-value language is venerable C, but it does not have arrays as "first-class" values, implicitly passing around pointers to their memory blocks instead and allowing names of array-typed variables and pointers to their first elements be used interchangeably.

P.S.

As to Java and .NET, since you have asked…

In Java, values of "primitive" types (like integers) are passed by value, and values of "complex" types (those defined using the `class` keyword) are passed around via pointers though it *looks* like they're passed by value.  So it mostly looks like Python and PHP.

.NET explicitly divides all *types* it supports (and the user is able to define) into the two broad categories:

- Value types — include primitive types and structural types defined using the `struct` keyword.
- Class types — everything else including user types defined using the `class` keyword.

Instances of value types are passed by value (their contents are copied) while instances of class types are passed by reference though this is implicit, like in Java etc.